Does this code guarantee that a Python object is deleted immediately?
I am using the Redis asynchronous client with Celery but I have had some problems with the integration between the two. The context is that I need to delete the redis.Redis instance (created in the constructor) so that the connections are closed (That object has a close method but I can't use it when the asyncio event loop is closed, the heal_client method is only would use in those cases.
My code is the following:
import redis.asyncio as redis

from app.infra.services.notifications import INotifier
from app.schemas.notification import NotificationMessage
from app.config import settings

        
class RedisNotifier(INotifier):
    def __init__(self):
        self.redis_client = redis.Redis(
        host=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_HOST,
        port=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_PORT,
        password=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_PASSWORD,
    )

    async def send_notification(self, room: str, notification: NotificationMessage) -> None:
        await self.redis_client.publish(room, notification.json())

    def heal_client(self) -> None:
        import gc
        
        del self.redis_client
        gc.collect()
        self.redis_client.close()
        self.redis_client = redis.Redis(
            host=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_HOST,
            port=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_PORT,
            password=settings.REDIS_PUBSUB_PASSWORD,
        )
        return None


redis_notifier = RedisNotifier()

# NOTIFIER is a global constant. Changing its value here will change the 
# notifier used throughout the entire project.
NOTIFIER = redis_notifier

My question is whether calling the heal_client method will always guarantee that the redis.Redis object (created in the constructor) will be deleted immediately?
This is how I usually use that method:
@celery_app.task(
    retry_backoff=True,
    max_retries=5,
    acks_late=True,
    name="charlie-update-session",  # bind=True, max_retries=2, acks_late=True,
)
def update_session(username: str, current_id: int, type_action: str):
    '''
    To avoid unexpected behaivor in the redis asynchronous client for notifications, it is
    necessary that all tasks use the same event loop. Celery prefork with concurrency 1
    guarantees a single OS Thread per worker, so we can use the same event loop associated
    with the Thread.
    '''
    log.info(f"[INFO]: A process of Update session was initiated. User: {username}")
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    loop = get_event_loop() 
    if loop.is_closed():
        loop = new_event_loop()
        set_event_loop(loop)
        if isinstance(NOTIFIER, RedisNotifier):
            NOTIFIER.heal_client()
    print(id(loop))
    task = loop.create_task(
        execute_update_data(
            username=username, current_id=current_id, type_action=type_action
        )
    )
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
    stop = timeit.default_timer()


No, there is no way to guarantee the deletion of an object in Python. There may be trickery to do it for a particular implementation like CPython but I don't know details.
